# JVM JNI dll crashed

Tags: java, dll, java-native-interface

I have a JNI dll built, if I use debug VC++ 2010 Express, it worked fine. If I use Release build, it crashed JVM.
This cmd: java -Djava.library.path=D:\charlie\tmp\SendKeys\x64\Debug SendKeys
worked.
This cmd:>java -Djava.library.path=D:\charlie\tmp\SendKeys\x64\Release -Dsun.java2d.d3d=false SendKeys
and cmd: >java -Djava.library.path=D:\charlie\tmp\SendKeys\x64\Release SendKeys  failed. Please help.

```
C++ native code(MS VC++ 2010 express), & in 64bits OS:


    BOOL __stdcall InitializeWinIo()
    {
        BOOL bResult = false;
        DWORD dwBytesReturned;
        g_Is64BitOS = Is64BitOS();
        hDriver = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\WINIO",GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
        0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,NULL);
        // If the driver is not running, install it
        if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
        {
            printf("WINIO driver is not running!\n");
            GetDriverPath();
            bResult = InstallWinIoDriver(szWinIoDriverPath, true);
            if (!bResult)
                return FALSE;
            bResult = StartWinIoDriver();
            if (!bResult)
            {
                printf("ERROR: WINIO driver can not be started!\n");
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("OK: WINIO driver has been started!\n");
            }
            hDriver = CreateFile(L"\\\\.\\WINIO",
                GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE,
                FILE_SHARE_READ | FILE_SHARE_WRITE,
                NULL,OPEN_EXISTING,
                FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL,
                NULL);
            if (hDriver == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
            {
                printf("ERROR: WINIO driver running status can not be confirmed!\n");
                return FALSE;
            }
            else
            {
                printf("ERROR: WINIO driver running status has been confirmed!\n");
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("WINIO driver is happily running!\n");
        }
        // Enable I/O port access for this process if running on a 32 bit OS
        if (!g_Is64BitOS)
        {
            printf("CRITICAL not a 64 bits system\n");
            if (!DeviceIoControl(hDriver, IOCTL_WINIO_ENABLEDIRECTIO, NULL,
                0, NULL, 0, &dwBytesReturned, NULL))
            {
                printf("ERROR: can not enable I/O access in 32 bits system\n");
                return FALSE;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            printf("OK a perfect 64 bits system\n");
        }
        IsWinIoInitialized = TRUE;
        return TRUE;
    }


#
# A fatal error has been detected by the Java Runtime Environment:
#
#  EXCEPTION_ACCESS_VIOLATION (0xc0000005) at pc=0x00000000000055b6, pid=4396, tid=9552
#
# JRE version: Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (7.0_80-b15) (build 1.7.0_80-b15)
# Java VM: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11 mixed mode windows-amd64 compressed oops)
# Problematic frame:
# C  0x00000000000055b6
#
# Failed to write core dump. Minidumps are not enabled by default on client versions of Windows
#
# If you would like to submit a bug report, please visit:
#   http://bugreport.java.com/bugreport/crash.jsp
# The crash happened outside the Java Virtual Machine in native code.
# See problematic frame for where to report the bug.
#

---------------  T H R E A D  ---------------

Current thread (0x00000000034c0800):  JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9552, stack(0x00000000033a0000,0x00000000034a0000)]

siginfo: ExceptionCode=0xc0000005, ExceptionInformation=0x0000000000000008 0x00000000000055b6

Registers:
RAX=0x00007ff6457b1780, RBX=0x000000077c8686e8, RCX=0x00007ff6457b43e0, RDX=0x000000000349f760
RSP=0x000000000349f6b8, RBP=0x000000000349f750, RSI=0x00000000ef8eccd3, RDI=0x00000000035c60f8
R8 =0x0000000000000000, R9 =0x0000000003508ec0, R10=0x00000000035d3124, R11=0x0000000072ba4b50
R12=0x0000000000000000, R13=0x000000077c8686e8, R14=0x000000000349f768, R15=0x00000000034c0800
RIP=0x00000000000055b6, EFLAGS=0x0000000000010206

Top of Stack: (sp=0x000000000349f6b8)
0x000000000349f6b8:   00007ff6457b1791 00000000ffffff00
0x000000000349f6c8:   00000000034c0800 000000077c8686e8
0x000000000349f6d8:   0000000000000000 00000007d5d598a8
0x000000000349f6e8:   00000000035d3150 0000000000000001
0x000000000349f6f8:   0000000000000000 00000000034c0800
0x000000000349f708:   000000000349f7c0 000000000349f710
0x000000000349f718:   000000077c8686e8 000000000349f768
0x000000000349f728:   000000077c869518 0000000000000000
0x000000000349f738:   000000077c8686e8 0000000000000000
0x000000000349f748:   000000000349f770 000000000349f7b0
0x000000000349f758:   00000000035c63f0 00000007d5d962b8
0x000000000349f768:   00000000035cf0c0 000000000349f770
0x000000000349f778:   000000077c8688b3 000000000349f7c0
0x000000000349f788:   000000077c869518 0000000000000000
0x000000000349f798:   000000077c868978 000000000349f770
0x000000000349f7a8:   000000000349f7c8 000000000349f808 

Instructions: (pc=0x00000000000055b6)
0x0000000000005596:   
[error occurred during error reporting (printing registers, top of stack, instructions near pc), id 0xc0000005]

Register to memory mapping:

RAX=0x00007ff6457b1780 is an unknown value
RBX=0x000000077c8686e8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
RCX=0x00007ff6457b43e0 is an unknown value
RDX=0x000000000349f760 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000034c0800
RSP=0x000000000349f6b8 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000034c0800
RBP=0x000000000349f750 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000034c0800
RSI=0x00000000ef8eccd3 is an unknown value
RDI=0x00000000035c60f8 is at code_begin+2520 in an Interpreter codelet
return entry points  [0x00000000035c5720, 0x00000000035c7520]  7680 bytes
R8 =0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R9 =0x0000000003508ec0 is an unknown value
R10=0x00000000035d3124 is at code_begin+644 in an Interpreter codelet
method entry point (kind = native)  [0x00000000035d2ea0, 0x00000000035d3740]  2208 bytes
R11=0x0000000072ba4b50 is an unknown value
R12=0x0000000000000000 is an unknown value
R13=0x000000077c8686e8 is an oop
{method} 
 - klass: {other class}
R14=0x000000000349f768 is pointing into the stack for thread: 0x00000000034c0800
R15=0x00000000034c0800 is a thread


Stack: [0x00000000033a0000,0x00000000034a0000],  sp=0x000000000349f6b8,  free space=1021k
Native frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code, C=native code)
C  0x00000000000055b6
j  SendKeys.init()Z+19
j  SendKeys.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub
V  [jvm.dll+0x1d03d3]

Java frames: (J=compiled Java code, j=interpreted, Vv=VM code)
j  SendKeys.initializeWinIO()Z+0
j  SendKeys.init()Z+19
j  SendKeys.main([Ljava/lang/String;)V+27
v  ~StubRoutines::call_stub

---------------  P R O C E S S  ---------------

Java Threads: ( => current thread )
  0x000000000b94b800 JavaThread "Service Thread" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=5812, stack(0x000000000d0a0000,0x000000000d1a0000)]
  0x000000000b941800 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread1" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7764, stack(0x000000000cfa0000,0x000000000d0a0000)]
  0x000000000b93f000 JavaThread "C2 CompilerThread0" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9736, stack(0x000000000cea0000,0x000000000cfa0000)]
  0x000000000b93e000 JavaThread "Attach Listener" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=6772, stack(0x000000000cda0000,0x000000000cea0000)]
  0x000000000b93b000 JavaThread "Signal Dispatcher" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=10512, stack(0x000000000cca0000,0x000000000cda0000)]
  0x000000000b8ee000 JavaThread "Finalizer" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=9768, stack(0x000000000cba0000,0x000000000cca0000)]
  0x000000000b8e5000 JavaThread "Reference Handler" daemon [_thread_blocked, id=7876, stack(0x000000000caa0000,0x000000000cba0000)]
=>0x00000000034c0800 JavaThread "main" [_thread_in_native, id=9552, stack(0x00000000033a0000,0x00000000034a0000)]

Other Threads:
  0x000000000b8e0000 VMThread [stack: 0x000000000c9a0000,0x000000000caa0000] [id=11044]
  0x000000000b964800 WatcherThread [stack: 0x000000000d1a0000,0x000000000d2a0000] [id=8160]

VM state:not at safepoint (normal execution)

VM Mutex/Monitor currently owned by a thread: None

Heap
 PSYoungGen      total 38400K, used 1331K [0x00000007d5d00000, 0x00000007d8780000, 0x0000000800000000)
  eden space 33280K, 4% used [0x00000007d5d00000,0x00000007d5e4cdb8,0x00000007d7d80000)
  from space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000007d8280000,0x00000007d8280000,0x00000007d8780000)
  to   space 5120K, 0% used [0x00000007d7d80000,0x00000007d7d80000,0x00000007d8280000)
 ParOldGen       total 86016K, used 0K [0x0000000781800000, 0x0000000786c00000, 0x00000007d5d00000)
  object space 86016K, 0% used [0x0000000781800000,0x0000000781800000,0x0000000786c00000)
 PSPermGen       total 21504K, used 2473K [0x000000077c600000, 0x000000077db00000, 0x0000000781800000)
  object space 21504K, 11% used [0x000000077c600000,0x000000077c86a618,0x000000077db00000)

Card table byte_map: [0x0000000006680000,0x0000000006aa0000] byte_map_base: 0x0000000002a9d000

Polling page: 0x0000000001aa0000

Code Cache  [0x00000000035c0000, 0x0000000003830000, 0x00000000065c0000)
 total_blobs=169 nmethods=0 adapters=137 free_code_cache=48771Kb largest_free_block=49942400

Compilation events (0 events):
No events

GC Heap History (0 events):
No events

Deoptimization events (0 events):
No events

Internal exceptions (2 events):
Event: 0.085 Thread 0x00000000034c0800 Threw 0x00000007d5d0f620 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jni.cpp:3991
Event: 0.365 Thread 0x00000000034c0800 Threw 0x00000007d5d91630 at C:\re\jdk7u80\2329\hotspot\src\share\vm\prims\jvm.cpp:1319

Events (10 events):
Event: 0.369 loading class 0x00000000034c9380
Event: 0.369 loading class 0x00000000034c9380 done
Event: 0.369 loading class 0x000000000352a970
Event: 0.369 loading class 0x000000000352a970 done
Event: 0.369 loading class 0x0000000003506550
Event: 0.369 loading class 0x0000000003506550 done
Event: 0.370 loading class 0x00000000035121b0
Event: 0.370 loading class 0x00000000035121b0 done
Event: 0.370 loading class 0x0000000003512150
Event: 0.370 loading class 0x0000000003512150 done


Dynamic libraries:
0x00007ff6fef00000 - 0x00007ff6fef33000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\java.exe
0x00007ff9ef7d0000 - 0x00007ff9ef9a1000     C:\WINDOWS\SYSTEM32\ntdll.dll
0x00007ff9ef640000 - 0x00007ff9ef6eb000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNEL32.DLL
0x00007ff9ec0c0000 - 0x00007ff9ec2dd000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\KERNELBASE.dll
0x00007ff9eee60000 - 0x00007ff9eef02000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ADVAPI32.dll
0x00007ff9ecd60000 - 0x00007ff9ecdfe000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\msvcrt.dll
0x00007ff9ee3d0000 - 0x00007ff9ee429000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\sechost.dll
0x00007ff9eeb60000 - 0x00007ff9eec81000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\RPCRT4.dll
0x00007ff9ee8b0000 - 0x00007ff9eea15000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\USER32.dll
0x00007ff9ec030000 - 0x00007ff9ec04e000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\win32u.dll
0x00007ff9ece10000 - 0x00007ff9ece44000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\GDI32.dll
0x00007ff9ecbd0000 - 0x00007ff9ecd52000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\gdi32full.dll
0x00007ff9dcc70000 - 0x00007ff9dceea000     C:\WINDOWS\WinSxS\amd64_microsoft.windows.common-controls_6595b64144ccf1df_6.0.14393.953_none_42151e83c686086b\COMCTL32.dll
0x00007ff9ee550000 - 0x00007ff9ee818000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\combase.dll
0x00007ff9ecad0000 - 0x00007ff9ecbc5000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\ucrtbase.dll
0x00007ff9ec050000 - 0x00007ff9ec0ba000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\bcryptPrimitives.dll
0x00007ff9ef7a0000 - 0x00007ff9ef7ce000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\IMM32.DLL
0x0000000073670000 - 0x0000000073742000     C:\charlie\Java\jre7\bin\msvcr100.dll
0x00000000729c0000 - 0x0000000073199000     C:\charlie\Java\jre7\bin\server\jvm.dll
0x00007ff9eec90000 - 0x00007ff9eec98000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\PSAPI.DLL
0x00007ff9e8590000 - 0x00007ff9e8599000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WSOCK32.dll
0x00007ff9ee360000 - 0x00007ff9ee3ca000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\WS2_32.dll
0x00007ff9e9eb0000 - 0x00007ff9e9ed3000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMM.dll
0x00007ff9e9e70000 - 0x00007ff9e9e9b000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\WINMMBASE.dll
0x00007ff9ebcc0000 - 0x00007ff9ebd02000     C:\WINDOWS\System32\cfgmgr32.dll
0x0000000073660000 - 0x000000007366f000     C:\charlie\Java\jre7\bin\verify.dll
0x0000000073630000 - 0x0000000073658000     C:\charlie\Java\jre7\bin\java.dll
0x0000000073610000 - 0x0000000073626000     C:\charlie\Java\jre7\bin\zip.dll
0x00007ff6457b0000 - 0x00007ff6457ca000     D:\charlie\tmp\SendKeys\x64\Release\SendKeys.dll
0x00007ff9e7150000 - 0x00007ff9e72e2000     C:\WINDOWS\system32\dbghelp.dll

VM Arguments:
jvm_args: -Djava.library.path=D:\charlie\tmp\SendKeys\x64\Release 
java_command: SendKeys
Launcher Type: SUN_STANDARD

Environment Variables:
JAVA_HOME=C:\charlie\Java\jdk1.7.0_80
PATH=C:\Python27\;C:\Python27\Scripts;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\Program Files\Intel\iCLS Client\;C:\WINDOWS\system32;C:\WINDOWS;C:\WINDOWS\System32\Wbem;C:\WINDOWS\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\DAL;C:\Program Files\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\Intel\Intel(R) Management Engine Components\IPT;C:\Program Files (x86)\ATI Technologies\ATI.ACE\Core-Static;C:\Program Files (x86)\Skype\Phone\;C:\Program Files\Git\cmd;C:\Program Files\Git\mingw64\bin;C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseGit\bin;C:\Program Files\TortoiseSVN\bin;C:\Program Files\MATLAB\MATLAB Runtime\v85\runtime\win64;C:\Program Files (x86)\PuTTY\;C:\Program Files\OpenVPN\bin;C:\Program Files (x86)\WinMerge;C:\Program Files\Microsoft SQL Server\110\Tools\Binn\；D:\charlie\tmp\SendKeys\x64\Debug\;C:\charlie\Java\jdk1.7.0_80\bin;C:\charlie\eclipse4.5.1\plugins\org.apache.ant_1.9.4.v201504302020\bin；C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.5\bin；;C:\Users\charlie\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps;C:\charlie\apache-maven-3.3.3\bin
USERNAME=charlie
OS=Windows_NT
PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER=Intel64 Family 6 Model 61 Stepping 4, GenuineIntel



---------------  S Y S T E M  ---------------

OS: Windows 8.1 , 64 bit Build 9600 

CPU:total 4 (2 cores per cpu, 2 threads per core) family 6 model 61 stepping 4, cmov, cx8, fxsr, mmx, sse, sse2, sse3, ssse3, sse4.1, sse4.2, popcnt, avx, avx2, aes, erms, ht, tsc, tscinvbit

Memory: 4k page, physical 8289204k(3876444k free), swap 9599924k(3279704k free)

vm_info: Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (24.80-b11) for windows-amd64 JRE (1.7.0_80-b15), built on Apr 10 2015 11:26:34 by "java_re" with unknown MS VC++:1600

time: Tue Apr 18 18:01:32 2017
elapsed time: 0 seconds
```

Comment: So, what do `SendKeys.init` and `SendKeys.initializeWinIO` look like?

Comment: *if I use debug VC++ 2010 Express, it worked fine. If I use Release build, it crashed JVM.* That's evidence your code in your native DLL is corrupting memory.

Comment: java code init(): System.loadlibrary("SendKeys"); initializeWinIO();

Comment: @Michael, Andrew, thanks for response, can you have a look at the java init() above & C++ native code below? Thanks

Comment: Please don't post code about your problem as an answer. Edit your question.

Comment: ok @manuell, thanks